# Access to the path (under web application) is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

To simplify the question:

I deployed a Web Application named `Equipment` on `serverABC` (`\\serverABC\Equipment*`)

The user will copy a file under the source path of the application `\\serverABC\Equipment\Folder1\...\File1.xls` by the function:

```
System.IO.File.Copy ( strSourceFile, strDestFile, true );

strSourceFile ="\\\serverABC\Equipment\Folder1\...\File1.xls"
```

In the `properties -> Security` of folder `\\serverABC\Equipment\Folder1`, I assigned read and write permission to **Network Service**, which is the application pool identity of the web application.

Then I got this error when using the web:

> Access to the path '\\serverABC\Equipment\Folder1...\File1.xls' is denied.

I don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: I believe you need to use a Server.MapPath on "~/Folder1/..." and use a **local path** rather than UNC path in order for the application pool identity to be able to access the directory. It's also worth double checking that it is actually network service and not "IIS AppPool/ *yourapplicationpool* " that you need to add permissions for. This will depend on your application pool settings and version of IIS.

Comment: It seems that the problem is the UNC path format and I need to share this folder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to use the server name since it is in the same server.

Since you want to save to a directory in your application use this:

```
string path = Server.MapPath("Folder1");
```

Then concatenate this with your file name and use in the `System.IO.File.Copy`.

Comment: For concatenation, don't do it by hand, just use **Path.Combine(folderPath, fileName)** ;-) Will save you some headaches...

Comment: @Ethenyl ...because we never remember if we already have the \ or / there. ahaha. It's a must.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Just out of curiosity, I want to know what should I do if I want to keep the path unchanged. Do I need to share Folder1 to Network Service (although they are on the same server)?

Comment: @Lucius actually I don't know if this method you are using works across network paths. Maybe you should try with a Console application first.